# How to get value outside if else block in Java

Tags: java

```
if (otpa !=null)
{
    aotp = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("otpa"));
    p = aotp * x;
    out.println(p);
    Double totb = a - p;
}
else  
{
    out.println("nothing");
}
String otpb = request.getParameter("otpb");
if (otpb !=null)
{
    Double botp = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("otpb"));
    q = botp * y;
    out.println(q);
    Double tot2 = b - q;
}
else
{
    out.println("nothing");
}
String otpc = request.getParameter("otpc");
if (otpc !=null)
{
    Double cotp = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("otpc"));
    r = cotp * z;
    out.println(r);
    Double tot3 = c - r;
}
else
{
    out.println("nothing");
}
```

I have created program. In this I want to use variables which is already calculated like e.g if `(d == null) { c=a+b }` and the outside if else I want to print value of c, but the time I print c it gives error that c is empty but believe  me guys it's not empty. 
I have tried in debugging there is no calculation error. I get all the calculated values as I want, but not getting outside if else condition I don't know why.

Comment: Can you be more clear? The code in the link and the description do not match. Some clear code would also help.

Comment: Look this here i want print variable totb outside if else condition how do i do that https://jsfiddle.net/2dg0er43/1/

Comment: LINK https://jsfiddle.net/2dg0er43/1/

Comment: You just need to declare totb before the line `if (otpa !=null)`

Comment: i have tried that but when i'm goint to write out.println(totb); outside if else it give error that totb is variable is not declared.

Comment: Can you post the exact error/stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (otpa !=null)
{
    aotp = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("otpa"));
    p = aotp * x;
    out.println(p);
    Double totb = a - p;
}
else  
{
    out.println("nothing");
}
```

to

```
Double totb = 0.0;
if (otpa !=null)
{
    aotp = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("otpa"));
    p = aotp * x;
    out.println(p);
    totb = a - p;
}
else  
{
    out.println("nothing");
}
```

Comment: Thanks YOU SO MUCH BlackPearl :)